# Computing variable transformation combinations with every variable present in every combination in R

Tags: r, variables, combinations, transformation

I try to ask the question again, hopefully in a better way!
I would like a resultant dataframe where var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7, var8, var9 is present in each model. Each of the 9 variables can then be either not be transformed or ln transformed.

```
var <- c(paste0("var", 1:9), paste0("lnvar", 1:9))
df <- as.data.frame (t(combn(var, 9))) 
df$name <- paste0("model", 1:nrow(df))


head(df)
    V1   V2   V3   V4   V5   V6   V7   V8     V9   name
1 var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var7 var8   var9 model1
2 var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var7 var8 lnvar1 model2
3 var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var7 var8 lnvar2 model3
4 var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var7 var8 lnvar3 model4
5 var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var7 var8 lnvar4 model5
6 var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var7 var8 lnvar5 model6
```

From the above code it makes many thousand models. My problem is that for example model2 where var 1 is present twice. The only model I can use is model1, in the above.

So my question is: 
How can I tell R to make all the nine variables present in all the models?

(I should end up with only 81 models as far as my calculations go.)
Until now this formula has worked: 
r=number of variables; n=variable transformations
Possibilities of combinations=r^n, so that when r=9, n=2, I get 9^2 possibilites=81 possibilities fits quite well.

I suspect that I’m stuck when considering the names of the variables, and that there is a smart function in R that I just don’t know of, or that it even is very easy to write a homemade function.
I just can’t see the solution.
So please if you have any clues what I can do I would be really great-full.

Comment: If each variable can be original or log-transformed, you're looking at 2^9 = 512 different combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x <- rep(list(c("","ln")),9)
x <- mapply(paste0, x, paste0("var",1:9), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
x <- expand.grid(x,KEEP.OUT.ATTRS = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
str(x)
#'data.frame':   512 obs. of  9 variables:
# $ Var1: chr  "var1" "lnvar1" "var1" "lnvar1" ...
# $ Var2: chr  "var2" "var2" "lnvar2" "lnvar2" ...
# $ Var3: chr  "var3" "var3" "var3" "var3" ...
# $ Var4: chr  "var4" "var4" "var4" "var4" ...
# $ Var5: chr  "var5" "var5" "var5" "var5" ...
# $ Var6: chr  "var6" "var6" "var6" "var6" ...
# $ Var7: chr  "var7" "var7" "var7" "var7" ...
# $ Var8: chr  "var8" "var8" "var8" "var8" ...
# $ Var9: chr  "var9" "var9" "var9" "var9" ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I came up with:

```
# Set up 9 variables and one possible transformation for each of those 9 variables
var <- c(paste0("var", 1:9), paste0("lnvar", 1:9))

# Calculate popssible combinations
df <- as.data.frame(t(combn(var, 2)))

# Add column with model name
df$name <- paste0("model", 1:nrow(df)) 

> df
        V1     V2     name
1     var1   var2   model1
2     var1   var3   model2
3     var1   var4   model3
4     var1   var5   model4
5     var1   var6   model5
6     var1   var7   model6
7     var1   var8   model7
8     var1   var9   model8
9     var1 lnvar1   model9
10    var1 lnvar2  model10
11    var1 lnvar3  model11
12    var1 lnvar4  model12
13    var1 lnvar5  model13
14    var1 lnvar6  model14
15    var1 lnvar7  model15
16    var1 lnvar8  model16
17    var1 lnvar9  model17
18    var2   var3  model18
19    var2   var4  model19
20    var2   var5  model20
21    var2   var6  model21
22    var2   var7  model22
23    var2   var8  model23
24    var2   var9  model24
25    var2 lnvar1  model25
26    var2 lnvar2  model26
27    var2 lnvar3  model27
28    var2 lnvar4  model28
29    var2 lnvar5  model29
30    var2 lnvar6  model30
31    var2 lnvar7  model31
32    var2 lnvar8  model32
33    var2 lnvar9  model33
34    var3   var4  model34
35    var3   var5  model35
36    var3   var6  model36
37    var3   var7  model37
38    var3   var8  model38
39    var3   var9  model39
40    var3 lnvar1  model40
41    var3 lnvar2  model41
42    var3 lnvar3  model42
43    var3 lnvar4  model43
44    var3 lnvar5  model44
45    var3 lnvar6  model45
46    var3 lnvar7  model46
47    var3 lnvar8  model47
48    var3 lnvar9  model48
49    var4   var5  model49
50    var4   var6  model50
51    var4   var7  model51
52    var4   var8  model52
53    var4   var9  model53
54    var4 lnvar1  model54
55    var4 lnvar2  model55
56    var4 lnvar3  model56
57    var4 lnvar4  model57
58    var4 lnvar5  model58
59    var4 lnvar6  model59
60    var4 lnvar7  model60
61    var4 lnvar8  model61
62    var4 lnvar9  model62
63    var5   var6  model63
64    var5   var7  model64
65    var5   var8  model65
66    var5   var9  model66
67    var5 lnvar1  model67
68    var5 lnvar2  model68
69    var5 lnvar3  model69
70    var5 lnvar4  model70
71    var5 lnvar5  model71
72    var5 lnvar6  model72
73    var5 lnvar7  model73
74    var5 lnvar8  model74
75    var5 lnvar9  model75
76    var6   var7  model76
77    var6   var8  model77
78    var6   var9  model78
79    var6 lnvar1  model79
80    var6 lnvar2  model80
81    var6 lnvar3  model81
82    var6 lnvar4  model82
83    var6 lnvar5  model83
84    var6 lnvar6  model84
85    var6 lnvar7  model85
86    var6 lnvar8  model86
87    var6 lnvar9  model87
88    var7   var8  model88
89    var7   var9  model89
90    var7 lnvar1  model90
91    var7 lnvar2  model91
92    var7 lnvar3  model92
93    var7 lnvar4  model93
94    var7 lnvar5  model94
95    var7 lnvar6  model95
96    var7 lnvar7  model96
97    var7 lnvar8  model97
98    var7 lnvar9  model98
99    var8   var9  model99
100   var8 lnvar1 model100
101   var8 lnvar2 model101
102   var8 lnvar3 model102
103   var8 lnvar4 model103
104   var8 lnvar5 model104
105   var8 lnvar6 model105
106   var8 lnvar7 model106
107   var8 lnvar8 model107
108   var8 lnvar9 model108
109   var9 lnvar1 model109
110   var9 lnvar2 model110
111   var9 lnvar3 model111
112   var9 lnvar4 model112
113   var9 lnvar5 model113
114   var9 lnvar6 model114
115   var9 lnvar7 model115
116   var9 lnvar8 model116
117   var9 lnvar9 model117
118 lnvar1 lnvar2 model118
119 lnvar1 lnvar3 model119
120 lnvar1 lnvar4 model120
121 lnvar1 lnvar5 model121
122 lnvar1 lnvar6 model122
123 lnvar1 lnvar7 model123
124 lnvar1 lnvar8 model124
125 lnvar1 lnvar9 model125
126 lnvar2 lnvar3 model126
127 lnvar2 lnvar4 model127
128 lnvar2 lnvar5 model128
129 lnvar2 lnvar6 model129
130 lnvar2 lnvar7 model130
131 lnvar2 lnvar8 model131
132 lnvar2 lnvar9 model132
133 lnvar3 lnvar4 model133
134 lnvar3 lnvar5 model134
135 lnvar3 lnvar6 model135
136 lnvar3 lnvar7 model136
137 lnvar3 lnvar8 model137
138 lnvar3 lnvar9 model138
139 lnvar4 lnvar5 model139
140 lnvar4 lnvar6 model140
141 lnvar4 lnvar7 model141
142 lnvar4 lnvar8 model142
143 lnvar4 lnvar9 model143
144 lnvar5 lnvar6 model144
145 lnvar5 lnvar7 model145
146 lnvar5 lnvar8 model146
147 lnvar5 lnvar9 model147
148 lnvar6 lnvar7 model148
149 lnvar6 lnvar8 model149
150 lnvar6 lnvar9 model150
151 lnvar7 lnvar8 model151
152 lnvar7 lnvar9 model152
153 lnvar8 lnvar9 model153
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer Majom! I’m sorry that I’m quite new to asking online R-questions, and that I didn’t make my problem clear enough from the beginning! I have now tried to edit the question using your coding example! Maybe you are still able to help me!